# Remounting tmpfs with a different size during boot

Tags: debian, systemd, mount, fstab, tmpfs

I have a custom Linux distribution (based on Debian), which has a lot of custom tooling for example changing system configurations (like network etc.

These configuration files are.json files, which are not specifically suited for Linux, and are retrieved from custom generators that generate the values from my configuration files within the corresponding Linux configuration.
These generators are systemd Units that are invoked in the **sysinit.target**.

I have a default entry in /etc/fstab which is being overwritten by the generator.
Afterwards im executing `sudo -o remount /tmp` to remount the tmpfs with the correct size. Sometimes it works, but other times it doesn't work and gives an error message that says: `"not mounted or bad option."`
I'm guessing this's a timing issue.

I have also read that this can be accomplished solely through the use of systemd (tmp.mount).
Could this work for my specific use case? Would it be possible to generate the unit file for tmp.mount during the boot process, so that the tmpfs is mounted with the correct size?

Everything must be automated. The system does not allow for manual interception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a default entry [for `/tmp` ] in `/etc/fstab` which is being overwritten by the generator. Afterwards I'm executing `sudo -o remount /tmp` to remount the tmpfs with the correct size. This seems to work sometimes, but other times the remount fails with the following `error: not mounted or bad option`. I suppose this is a timing problem.

One approach is to ensure that your generator only runs when `/tmp` is already mounted. You can use the [`RequiresMountsFor=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#RequiresMountsFor=) dependency for that in your systemd unit file of the service unit :

```
[Unit]
RequiresMountsFor=/tmp
...
```

---

An alternative is to set the default/placeholder `/tmp` entry in `/etc/fstab` with the `noauto` flag and then explicitly  mount `/tmp` only after your generator has set the desired size. i.e. run a mount command where you current use remount.

---

And a third alternative is to completely do away with the `/tmp` entry in `/etc/fstab` and have your generator script generate and execute a [`systemd-mount [OPTIONS...] --tmpfs [NAME] WHERE`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd-mount.html#) command line to mount `/tmp` as tmpfs.